# First time using smart pointers, am I doing it correctly?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have two classes. One that creates a resource, which is then sent to the other class which stores it for access by different parts of the program. What I do is:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;

ObjectPtr CreatorClass::Create()
{
    ObjectPtr(new Object);
    // ...
    return ObjectPtr;
}

void StorageClass::Store(ObjectPtr obj)
{
    myVector.push_back(obj);
}

ObjectPtr StorageClass::Get(int index)
{
    return myVector[index];
}
```

My questions are:

1. Am I correct in using `shared_ptr` or should I use something else?
2. Should I be passing `ObjectPtr` by value to Store function and from Get function?

Comment: @cdhowie This question seems to be stub code, example code or pseudo-code, which is **off-topic** on Code Review. Code Review is meant for **real working code**.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm afraid Ismael is correct. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I correct in using shared_ptr or should I use something else?

You are correct if you need shared ownership. Otherwise you are wrong.

> Should I be passing ObjectPtr by value to Store function

Yes. Although you *could* still do `.push_back(std::move(obj))` to avoid a needless copy.

> and from Get function?

Depends on whether you want to

- modify the original `shared_ptr` in the vector, then return by non-const reference,
- just observe it, then return by const reference
- none of the above, i.e. get you own copy of it, then return by value.

Comment: Might `.emplace_back()` be even better?

Comment: @cdhowie No, it's exactly as good (in this case).

Comment: By shared ownership, do you mean other classes just using the pointer, or editing the underlying object?

Comment: @Moody By shared ownership I mean multiple pointers owning the same object. By "owning" I mean "responsible for calling `delete`".

Comment: So shared ownership simply means that `delete` will be called on the managed object when the last remaining `shared_ptr` that points to that object gets destroyed.

Comment: In contrast to unique ownership, where only one pointer (`unique_ptr`) manages (= is responsible for calling `delete` on) a given object.

Comment: Only the StorageClass can delete the object, so only single ownership exists. But other classes need access to the pointer. Wouldn't returning a unique_ptr cause the copy inside the vector in StorageClass to be invalidated?

Comment: Then I guess you should be using `unique_ptr` (it should be the default go-to smart pointer type anyway; only use `shared_ptr` if `unique_ptr` isn't enough).

Comment: And no, `unique_ptr` _can't_ be copied (otherwise it wouldn't be very unique). If you need to return the `unique_ptr` then return it by reference. If you only need to return the object that the `unique_ptr` manages, then dereference the `unique_ptr` and return a reference to that object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally speaking, you are not doing it very efficiently. I see multiple issues with the code, almost close to antipattern.

1. Omnipresent Creators. My gosh, I hate them. What's the point of a
   'creator' in your example? Why can't the object be created by the
   user directly?
2. Store function. It has two issues. First it does nothing apart putting an element to the vector, coupled with sister get, which
   simply extracts. Given that, those two functions should be sent to
   meet their Creator (pun intended). Instead, myVector should be
   exposed to class users. Otherwise, you are severely limiting user
   experience (for instance, how would they even know if they can call
   get with given index? They don't know the size of the vector!). Avoid
   getters and setters.
3. Second issue with Store - if we imagine that Store does more than simply pushing stuff to vector, and thus it's existence is justified,
   it accepts shared pointer by value. Which means, you are atomically
   incrementing the counter. Performance weeps. Pass shared pointer by
   reference to reduce the impact. Better yet, do not use shared
   ponters. There usage is not justified in 99% cases I've seen.

Comment: I just used those names to simplify the example :). The Creator class is actually an Importer that loads different formats from disc and converts to a single format to be used in the program. The Storage class also handles object selection (It's a 3D editor) and deletion.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by pass the shared_ptr by reference? The "Creator" class only has a local copy.

Comment: Passing by reference was suggested in regards to input parameter for Store function.